# Failed to push selection: Read-only file system : while moving to SdCard

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have created a SDCard from my music player app. But when i add songs to the app it is showing error that

```
     [2013-01-23 16:09:18 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
     [2013-01-23 16:09:18] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

I have set `uses-permission` in my `Manifest`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What might be wrong. Please help me out this issue.

Comment: permission code  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 6):

Go to  sdk/platform-tools directory (to get access to the adb shell) then I typed the following commands:

```
./adb shell 
su 
mount -o rw,remount rootfs / 
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
```

Then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions in Android manifest file for accessing Sd Card.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```